# Why does my code always always throw "the active chart doesn't contain the study" error?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

Bollinger Bands and Fibonacci retracement trading strategy

Bollinger Bands settings:

```
length = input(20, minval=1, title="Length")
mult = input(2, minval=0, title="Std Dev Multiplier")
```

Bollinger Bands calculation:

```
upper = sma(close, length) + mult * stdev(close, length)
lower = sma(close, length) - mult * stdev(close, length)
```

Fibonacci retracement levels:

```
trend = trendmode.linear
start = low
end = high
ret61 = retrace(start, end, 61.8)
ret50 = retrace(start, end, 50)
ret38 = retrace(start, end, 38.2)
```

Plotting

```
plot(upper, color=color.red, linecolor=color.red, linewidth=2, title="Upper Band")
plot(lower, color=color.green, linecolor=color.green, linewidth=2, title="Lower Band")
plot(ret61, color=color.yellow, linecolor=color.yellow, linewidth=2, title="61.8%")
plot(ret50, color=color.orange, linecolor=color.orange, linewidth=2, title="50%")
plot(ret38, color=color.purple, linecolor=color.purple, linewidth=2, title="38.2%")
```

Buy signal:

```
buy = cross(close, upper)
plotshape(buy, shape=shape.arrowup, color=color.green, location=location.bottom)
```

Sell signal:

```
sell = cross(close, lower)
plotshape(sell, shape=shape.arrowdown, color=color.red, location=location.bottom)
```

My code keeps on returning the active chart doesn't contain the study that I am trying to publish. What is there to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the script that you are trying to publish to your chart and then try to publish.

> Prepare your chart. Load your script on the chart and remove other
> scripts or drawings that won’t help users understand your script. Your
> script’s plots should be easy to identify on the chart that will be
> published with it.

See [this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/Publishing_scripts.html#preparing-a-publication) for more information.